# Why adding new user to Remote desktop group doesn't automatically creates him a folder in C:\users

Tags: windows, users

I am administrating a remote Windows Server 2008 Standard. I have already 17 users in 'Remote Desktop Users' and all of them have home folders in c:\users. 
But when I've added the 18th user it didn't create a folder for him. 
Can you someone please suggest a reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason: I've deleted the user folder under c:\users manually some time ago. And now when the same user log in, it creates folder like c:\users\TEMP_XXX

Answer (score 3):

Have the previous 17 users logged on? It's my understanding that the user folder is created on first log in.

Adding someone to Remote Desktop Users just gives them permission to remote onto appropriately configured devices.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The folder is created after the first login. All the 17 users have been logged in an they have folders, but the 18th even after successfully log in doesn't have folder.

Comment: If the user logged on successfully, there's definitely a profile folder for him *somewhere*.  Get him to create a file on the desktop and then right-click on it and select Properties to see the location.